Add Self-Service Scheduling to Your Experience Builder Site - Null error in getServiceAppointment
We are trying to add Self-Service Scheduling to our Experience Builder Site according to instructions here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mfs_appointment_assistant_sss_existing_appointments_parent.htm&type=5
Digital Experience site being used is login-restricted so this is not available for guest users.
When the component is added to the site and I log in with my test user I can see in the console log that there is an error getting Service Appointment in the managed lwc aaRebookingMain.js.
Error printed in the console:

"getServiceAppointment error is : Error: System.NullPointerException:
Attempt to de-reference a null object at eval
(aaRebookingMain.js:1:8947)"

Since this is a managed package there seems to be no way for me to see why this error is happening and that the null object is being referenced.
Do you have any information on how to debug this or better, what might be the issue?

Welcome to SFSE. Have you checked the permissions assigned to the community users, making sure that they have the permission set license assigned to enable access to the underlying objects? This kind of error is typical of a permission issue. I'm assuming you have completed the steps here
